# PostGIS & Python SQL Query formatting: Create Geometry only for entries that are not NULL

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, postgis-2.3

I think this is rather a formatting issue. I have a database with a geometry Column that sometimes contains points. Normally, it will be None/Null.

When I format the SQL query in psychopg2 and python (for inserting entries), it looks like this:

```py
insert_sql = '''
        INSERT INTO "post" (post_guid, post_latlng)
        VALUES (%s,ST_GeomFromText(%s,4326))
        ON CONFLICT (post_guid)
        DO UPDATE SET
            post_latlng = COALESCE(EXCLUDED.post_latlng, "post".post_latlng),                            
        '''
cursor.execute(insert_sql,(post_guid,photo_latlng))
```

However, this does not work if `photo_latlng = None`
I tried:

```py
if geoinformation_available:
    photo_latlng = "POINT(%s %s)" % (photo_longitude,photo_latitude) #WKTconversion
else:
    photo_latlng = None
if not photo_latlng == None:
    photo_latlng = "ST_GeomFromText(" + photo_latlng + ",4326)"    
insert_sql = '''
        INSERT INTO "post" (post_guid, post_latlng)
        VALUES (%s,%s)
        ON CONFLICT (post_guid)
        DO UPDATE SET
            post_latlng = COALESCE(EXCLUDED.post_latlng,"post".post_latlng)                            
        '''
cursor.execute(insert_sql,(post_guid,photo_latlng))
```

.. but it gives me a psycopg2.InternalError: parse error - invalid geometry
(HINT:  "ST" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry). I also doubt that this will work with COALESCE -> only fill row if entry is not Null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`photo_latlng` will never be null as is always contains at least `"POINT(  )"`. You need to validate that the coordinates are or not null. If they are null, you insert a null geometry, else, you construct the proper geometry.

```
newgeom = "NULL"
if not photo_longitude == None and  not photo_latitude== None:
   newgeom = " ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(%s %s), 4326) " % (photo_longitude,photo_latitude) 

#no change to the sql
insert_sql = '''
        INSERT INTO "post" (post_guid, post_latlng)
        VALUES (%s,%s)
        ON CONFLICT (post_guid)
        DO UPDATE SET
            post_latlng = COALESCE(EXCLUDED.post_latlng,"post".post_latlng)                            
        '''
#use the new geometry/null geometry
cursor.execute(insert_sql,(post_guid,newgeom ))
```

Comment: Thank you JGH, this is even better - I was not aware that I could use `ST_GeomFromText` outside the SQL statement!

Comment: I am not using it, I am just writing the text that is embedded in the SQL. All the geometry construction takes place in the DB, not in the python code

Comment: I should have tested this first - this approach does not work JGH, I am getting the error `psycopg2.InternalError: parse error - invalid geometry
LINE 3: ...'ST_GeomFr...                                                             ^
HINT:  "ST" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry`, perhaps because newgeom  is submitted in string-formatting - see my answer below

Comment: could you print `insert_sql  % (post_guid,newgeom)` just before executing the query?

Comment: This is the output: `...],ST_GeomFromText(POINT(-3.530175 39.474307) ,4326))...` it looks all correct. I don't understand why there's an error. This gives me the same SQL_output string but without the error: `if photo_latlng == None:                            
    geoconvertOrNone = "%s"                         
else:                                               
    geoconvertOrNone = "ST_GeomFromText(%s,4326)"   ` (see my solution)

Comment: Ah yes, it's missing the ' around the text point. See the edit (faster way and no geometry string)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I think this will work - will report back later after I have tested this (my script is currently busy transferring data to the server, after it is finsihed I can implement your code)

Answer (score 0):

See above (better) answer from JGH. This was my solution (also works, but kind of ugly):

```py
photo_latlng = "POINT(%s %s)" % (photo_longitude,photo_latitude) #WKTconversion
if photo_latlng == None:
    geometry = "%s"
else:    
    geometry = "ST_GeomFromText(%s,4326)" 
insert_sql = '''
        INSERT INTO "post" (post_guid, post_latlng)
        VALUES (%s,''' + geometry + ''')
        ON CONFLICT (post_guid)
        DO UPDATE SET
            post_latlng = COALESCE(EXCLUDED.post_latlng, "post".post_latlng),                            
        '''
cursor.execute(insert_sql,(post_guid,photo_latlng))
```